# Render jinja2 template from string with page context

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Basically, I want to create editor, where you can edit part of the page using jinja2 syntax. In editor, if you press *Preview*, I want to be able see rendered template included into page, but with all variables and custom filters which page itself has. My current code is:

**Python**

```
from flask import render_template
from jinja2 import Template

# (... route logic here ...)
return render_template('preview.html',
   title='Some title',
   preview=Template("This is {{ title }}.")
```

**Jinja2**

```
{{ title }}
{{ preview.render() }}
```

But output is:

```
Some title
This is .
```

Is it possible to render my template from string with page context that output will be like this?

```
Some title
This is Some title.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

If you want to render a sub template and inherit the context from the parent template, then you can use `include`, which is usually used with a template path (e.g., `{% include 'template.html' %}` but also works with a `Template` object:

```
{{ title }}
{% include preview %}
```

*Original Answer*

You need to pass the context to preview.render() in the first template. Try this:

```
{{ title }}
{{ preview.render(title=title) }}
```

Comment: I know I can pass variables as a parameter, but is it possible do it somehow without passing them? Something what will "paste" my template from string and process it with main template in one run with context?

Comment: Ah. In that case you can use `include`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much, I didn't know it's possible to include Template object as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72390604/11627404  another method