# how to extend a jinja2 template with a super block that is a string in the same Python script

Tags: python, jinja2

I don't understand how to extend a jinja2 template with a super block that is a string in the same Python script

Sample code

```
from jinja2 import Template

hello = """
hello
"""

world = """
{% extends 'hello' %}
world
"""

j2_template = Template(world)
print(j2_template.render())
```

I want to print "hello world", obviously, but I get an error

```
TypeError: no loader for this environment specified
```

I checked the Jinja2 loader doc, but cannot find how to ref a string as a super block.
Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja doesn't know where `hello` template is. You need to remove `{% extends 'hello' %}` and render `hello` first and insert it as a variable in the string template.

```
world = Template("""{} world""".format(Template(hello).render()))
print(world.render())
```

Comment: tried this, but this returns "NameError: name 'data' is not defined"

Comment: alas .  this returns "AttributeError: 'Environment' object has no attribute 'get_source'"

Comment: Found a solution after researching for a while. Let me know if it resolves your problem.

Comment: Hi Shrandha, tks, this solves it. Noticed that it also works when I leave the {% extends 'hello' %} in. thanks a lot for helping me out.

Comment: This is basically the equivalent of not using jinja2 at all. We can essentially just use the str.format() According to this solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
from jinja2 import Environment, BaseLoader, DictLoader

loader = DictLoader({'hello': '<div>hello html</div>'})
# Need environment dictLoader object to loader
template_env = Environment(loader=loader, cache_size=1000)
template = template_env.from_string("<div>ss  {{name}} {% include 'hello' %} </div>")
dictt = {"name": "sumit"}
parsed_html = template.render(dictt)

# Parsed output in html string
```

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/
link of documentation

worked for me

Comment: Brilliant ! This basically also explains how jinja works.